# ACCESS 2003: Checking to see if record exists BEFORE UPDATE and then display message THEN OPEN existing record

Tags: ms-access-2003

Working on this for awhile now and i'm getting runtime error 2501

i'm trying to pull up a record after the message box appears stating that a duplicate has been found and upon clicking "OK" pulls up the record.

i have been tinkering with the DoCmd.FindRecord, DoCmd.GoToRecord, and DoCmd.OpenForm methods to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub MRN_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
Dim Answer As Variant
Answer = DLookup("[MRN]", "Requests Processed", "[MRN] = '" & Me.MRN & "'")
If Not IsNull(Answer) Then
MsgBox "Existing MRN found" & ": " & MRN.Text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please SEARCH and EDIT on EXISTING Record.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly + vbDefaultButton1, "EXISTING MRN FOUND"
Cancel = True
Me.MRN.Undo
Else:
End If
DoCmd.OpenForm "Requests Processed", , , Answer
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

From the help topic, the `OpenForm` method's *WhereCondition* option is "*A string expression that's a valid SQL WHERE clause without the word WHERE.*"

Try `OpenForm` this way ...

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm "Requests Processed", , , "[MRN] = '" & Answer & "'"
```

It looks to me like that could work.  However it seems you can use the same string for both your `DLookup` *Criteria* option and your `OpenForm` *WhereCondition*.  If that's true create one string variable (eg *strWhere*) and use it in both places.

Comment: just tried it and logically it should work but ran into Run-Time error 2501: The OpenForm action was cancelled.

thanks again for any pointers you may add.

Comment: Does that form open at all?  If you get that error with only `DoCmd.OpenForm "Requests Processed"` and no other options, the form may be corrupt.

Comment: Re-encoding the DoCmd.OpenForm "Requests Processed" without options opens the form without errors.  the form's current mode is in Create New Record status.

Comment: If "Create New Record status" means the form's Data Entry property is set to Yes, you can't ask it display an existing record ... which is what I thought you were trying to do.  You could over-ride the form's saved setting with `OpenForm` by using `acFormEdit` as the *DataMode* option ... in that case you could also supply your *WhereCondition* to make it display an existing record.  But I'm skeptical that's the explanation because I haven't found any combination of form settings and `OpenForm` options which triggers error #2501.  Afraid I'm stumped.

Comment: Hey thanks for the effort HansUp.  I was leaning towards the idea of having the user just click on a find button to sendfocus on the field that it found an existing record on to help minimize the mouse clicks.  thanks again.